# How can we get the Image Path or URL of createImageView in Titanium Developer using Javascript click addeventlistener?

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium

I have an ImageView, on click of the ImageView I would like to get the Image Path (image or url) inside the addEventListener, how can we achieve this. Or simply my question is how can we get the information of properties of ImageView when we click on the Image using click eventlistener in Titanium Developer using javascript.

```
img = Ti.UI.createImageView({
image: 'http://www.xyz.com/v2/media/Images/Venue/' + photoName + '?' + rand,
hires: 'true',
width: 70,
height: 60,
top: top,
left: left,
borderWidth: 3,
borderShadow: '000',
borderColor: '#FFF',
contentMode: 'aspectfull',                      
clipsToBounds: true

});

img.addEventListener('click', function(e)

          {

    });
```

Can we access imageview information from 'e' of 'click' event of the addEventListener ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do. The way @Muhammad Zeeshan has given is also works but only when your img object is visible or global.

If you want to access it using "e" object. You can access it like this,

```
img.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  var path = e.source.image;
});
```

you can access all the property of all ui controls in their event listeners using e.source.*

- = property name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,
Just do this.

```
img.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  var path = img.image;

});
```